# Automate task on Paypal payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have a site where I use Paypal for accepting payments.

It is a simple concept;
User enters some URL and makes Paypal payment. I use the same URL and add it on some 3rd party site.

My question is can I automate this process i.e. on Paypal payment, I take the URL and add it on the 3rd party website. 
The 3rd party site just requires me to login and add the URL there.
Are there some tools which can help me with this automation?

I am looking for free tools (may be some script or something), but would be fine if the charges are reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PayPal's IPN or PDT to return the information back to your system/script once the payment is complete so it can be automated.  Then you would just need to write the code to connect to the other site and update the site or file.  Keeping in mind I am not familiar with what options you have for updating the site with the URL, or how you have to go about specifically doing this.  If the site allows you to use FTP and upload a file or access their system and add the URL to a file I am sure this would not be an issue.  You may need to check with the service you are going to be using, and see what options you have for updating this information on there system of if they offer any type of API you can use.

Comment: Do you have some examples when you say write the code to connect to the other site ? Actually there is no FTP involved to connect to other site...It is like I neeed to go to xyz.com/addURL.php and add/submit the URL which was entered by the user on my site...